# SQL AND OR evaluating to different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem when using AND and OR in SQL.

This returns a single record:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SupplierName, r.ReturnID, r.Reason
FROM tblSupplierProducts sp, tblReturns r,tblSuppliers s
WHERE sp.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
AND r.Reason LIKE 'Unreadable disk'
```

This also returns a single record:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SupplierName, r.ReturnID, r.Reason
FROM tblSupplierProducts sp, tblReturns r,tblSuppliers s
WHERE sp.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
AND r.Reason LIKE 'Scratched CD'
```

But when I do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SupplierName, r.ReturnID, r.Reason
FROM tblSupplierProducts sp, tblReturns r,tblSuppliers s
WHERE sp.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
AND r.Reason LIKE 'Unreadable disk' 
OR r.Reason LIKE 'Scratched CD'
```

The 'Unreadable disk' results are present and correct
but the 'Scratched CD' is not ( it has the same value for every different supplier)
If i swap them like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SupplierName, r.ReturnID, r.Reason
FROM tblSupplierProducts sp, tblReturns r,tblSuppliers s
WHERE sp.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
AND r.Reason LIKE  'Scratched CD'
OR r.Reason LIKE 'Unreadable disk'
```

my first result is correct ('Scratched CD') while 'Unreadable disk' returns trhe same value for multiple suppliers.

It seems the AND OR is messing up the query why?

Comment: AND has precedence. Use parentheses. Do you mean `A AND (B or C)` or do you mean `(A AND B) or C`? SQL lets you express exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND takes precedence over OR, so when you do your OR statement, that is the only criterion being met.  Therefore, whichever statement is second in your query will have looser criteria.  You need to explcitly group your query, like:

```
WHERE sp.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
AND (r.Reason LIKE  'Scratched CD'
OR r.Reason LIKE 'Unreadable disk')
```

Answer (score 2):

LIKE is intended to use with a % wildcard to represent 0+ random chars.

use () when you combine AND and OR, to prevent ambiguous where clauses

Comment: `like` has two wildcard characters. Percent sign `%` matches 0 or more characters, underscore `_` matches any one character.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a problem with the order of operations. You should definitely use paranthesis to make sure that the logic is known. What it is doing implicitly is this:

```
    USE CNB_ONLINE
    SELECT DISTINCT s.SupplierName, r.ReturnID, r.Reason
    FROM tblSupplierProducts sp, tblReturns r,tblSuppliers s
    WHERE (sp.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
    AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
    AND r.Reason LIKE 'Unreadable disk')
 (OR r.Reason LIKE 'Scratched CD')
```

You should have the code like this:

```
    USE CNB_ONLINE
    SELECT DISTINCT s.SupplierName, r.ReturnID, r.Reason
    FROM tblSupplierProducts sp, tblReturns r,tblSuppliers s
    WHERE sp.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
    AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
    AND (r.Reason LIKE 'Unreadable disk' OR r.Reason LIKE 'Scratched CD')
```

You can find the order of precedence here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx and you'll notice that ANDs get evalulated before ORs.

Answer (score 1):

When you use LIKE, you really ought to put in some wildcard like `%`. Otherwise, if you are looking for a literal string, just use `=`.

Try wrapping parenthesis around the individual pieces of the WHERE clause to see if that helps:

```
AND sp.ProductID=r.productID
AND ((r.Reason = 'Scratched CD')
    OR (r.Reason = 'Unreadable disk'))
```